# Spherically symmetric potentials

Tags: symmetry, potential, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to calculate differential cross sections for a certain scattering problem. I want to use the approximate formula for the scattering amplitude in a spherically symmetric potential. Is any potential which only depends on the radial distance $r$ spherically symmetric? In particular, is the Yukawa potential spherically symmetric?

Comment: Indeed as long as its the magnitude of the radial vector you can prove it using a general rotation matrix acting on the radial vector. That is $r'=|\vec{r}'|=|R\vec{r}|=|\vec{r}|=r$ since for a general rotation matrix R they have unit determinant.

Answer (score 3):

Spherical symmetry literally means that something looks the same after you have performed an arbitrary three-dimensional rotation on it. So, yes indeed, if you have a potential that only depends on the radial distance $r$, then any three-dimensional rotation would leave the potential unaffected. Hence, it is spherically symmetric.